# Jquery Mobile - disabled dialog on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I have an initial init page in my application that acts as an entry point and loads my login page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-      1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>  
</head> 
<body>

<!-- initialse and load the application -->
<div data-role="page" id="init">

  <script type="text/javascript">   
    $('#init').live( 'pageinit', function() {
      window.location.href="views/login.html";
    });
  </script>

</div>

</body> 
</html>
```

When my login page loads there is a button which loads a dialog. This button initially doesn't work and only loads the dialog when the page is manually refreshed. Why does this happen and what can I do to enable the button/dialog immediately upon page load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <title></title> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>    
</head> 
<body>

<!-- login page -->
<div data-role="page" id="login">

<!-- css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/login.css" /> 
<!-- page markup -->    
  <div data-role="header">
    <a href="#settings_dialog" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="gear" data-theme="b">Settings</a>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- end of page -->


<!-- settings dialog page -->
<div data-role="dialog" id="settings_dialog">

<!-- page markup -->
  <div data-role="header" style="text-align: left;">
    <a href="" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-iconpos="left" data-inline="true"></a>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">

  </div>

</div>
<!-- end of page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've fixed this but it seems to be something to do with the DOM cache & AJAX.

I'm not sure how you'd do it, but try setting the `ajax: false` when you do the window reload. Alternatively you could redirect via server side (I'd recommend this as it'll still work if the user has JS turned off.

Why I figured this out was because I had a page with a list on it, the list items sent me to a new page which has a jump link on it (#settings_dialog). Setting the `data-ajax="false"` on each list item somehow 'refreshed' the DOM and forced the second page to load 'fresh' and voila - my dialog works 100% now.

So, in short, turn off the AJAX feature or (better) redirect from serverside & be happy!